# Showing the results in respective cells instead of a popup message box

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

The below code works perfectly, however,i want to change the way it shows result. Instead of the msgbox I want it to show results in cells next to the selected cell. Being naive in coding can't figure out a way to do this.

```
Sub GrammarCheck(xlRange As Excel.Range)

    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdRng As Object
    Dim wdRngIndex As Object
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim bOldOption As Boolean
    Dim rCell As Excel.Range
    Dim sTextToCheck As String

    'Create new Word instance
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Store the old CheckGrammer option and make sure it’s
    'currently set to True
    bOldOption = wdApp.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType
    wdApp.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = True

    'Create a new document and define a range
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
    Set wdRng = wdDoc.Range

    'Loop through the cells and build a string to stick into Word.
    For Each rCell In xlRange.Cells
        sTextToCheck = sTextToCheck & " " & rCell.Text
    Next rCell

    'Put the text into Word
    wdRng.Text = sTextToCheck

    'Count the grammatical errors
    If wdRng.GrammaticalErrors.Count = 0 Then
        sMsg = "No grammatical errors"
    Else
        'Initialize the prompt for the message box
        sMsg = "The following sentences have grammatical errors:" _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

        'Loop through the Word ranges that contain errors
        For Each wdRngIndex In wdRng.GrammaticalErrors
            sMsg = sMsg & Trim(wdRngIndex.Text) & vbNewLine
        Next wdRngIndex
    End If

    'Show result
    MsgBox sMsg, vbOKOnly, "Grammar Check"

    'Reset options and close everything
    wdApp.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = bOldOption
    wdDoc.Close False
    wdApp.Quit

    Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub

Sub TestGrammarSub()

    GrammarCheck Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")

End Sub
```

Comment: Code seems to be from [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/10/19/checking-grammar/). What did yo try on your own? Anything where we can help.

Comment: Why not  use  [CheckSpelling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.checkspelling?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133091)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) from Excel, but also [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/articles/feedback-support)